# User Authentication and 3 different tables

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm pretty new to Symfony2 framework and I'm trying to implement authentication in my system.

I have 3 different tables - workers (admin like), clients and subcarriers. Every user should have different adress to login form and login to different part of system. It is possible to do this in standard symfony security?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [documentation about security of symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

And you can use the Bundle FosUserBundle, the documentation [is here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle).

I guess you need to create three different roles for each table and then use groups with the bundle like it is explained [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/groups.md)

Answer (score 0):

If your application requires unique logic for each user type you will want to include the [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle). It adds a layer to FOSUserBundle to enable separate controllers and registration templates for each user type.